# Implementing a simple allocator class using malloc() and free()

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management, malloc

Is this simple implementation of an allocator acceptable

```
template<typename T>
class Allocator
{
public:
    T * allocate(int n);  //allocate space for n objects of type T 
    void deallocate(T* p, int n);  //deallocate n objects of type T starting at p

    void construct(T* p, const T& v);  //construct a T with the value v in p
    void destroy(T* p);  //destroy the T in p
};

template<typename T>
T* Allocator<T>::allocate(int n)
{
    T* new_mem = (T*)malloc(n * sizeof(T));
    return new_mem;
}

template<typename T>
void Allocator<T>::construct(T* p, const T& v)
{
    T* constructed_object = new(p) T{ v };
}

template<typename T>
void Allocator<T>::deallocate(T* p, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        free(&p[i]);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Allocator<T>::destroy(T* p)
{
    p->~T();
}
```

I'm to use it in a vector to implement function that reserves exra space as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void vector<T, A>::reserve(int newalloc)
{
    if (newalloc <= space)return;
    T* p = alloc.allocate(newalloc);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)alloc.construct(&p[i], elem[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)alloc.destroy(&elem[i]);
    elem = p;
    space = newalloc;
}
```

where `typename A = Allocator<T>` and `alloc` is of type `A`.
Will the allocator class I implemented be functional enough to work?
(I feel the `deallocate` function is suspect)

Comment: I guess placement new returns `void*` that may not happen to be `T*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deallocation function is indeed incorrect. The rules for `free` and `malloc` is simple: you must pass exactly the pointers you got from `malloc` to `free`.

```
template<typename T>
void Allocator<T>::deallocate(T* p, size_t)
{
    free(p);
}
```

Note you should in general pass the same pointer *type* to deallocation functions as well, but in this case since `free` only takes `void*` as parameter, the implicit conversion will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't going to work.

- You ought to have a `rebind` method.
- You need to provide comparison operators (`==` and `!=`)
- Your `allocate` method allocates too much. By the time it gets to you, the `sizeof(T)` has already happened.
- Your `deallocate` method is just wrong. You get a single pointer. The second parameter is a hint to the size of the allocation.
- The `construct` and `destruct` methods are optional. If you don't provide them, they will be synthesized for you by `allocator_traits`.

See https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/5a424a985612452d4f7a3f02422207456d54a53e/test/support/min_allocator.h#L21 for an example of a minimal allocator (albeit w/o a `rebind` )

Comment: The allocation function is correct. Your link confirms that.